# Create grid heatmap with axis corresponding to intervals in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a `ggplot` heatmap in `R` with the use of the command

```
ggplot() +                         
  geom_tile()
```

I have the following data

```
t_1 = c(-1,0,1,4)
t_2 = c(-2,-1,3)
W = c(1,10,3,4,17,9)
```

The `t_1` corresponds to intervals in x-axis, i.e. corresponds to `(-1,0)`, `(0,1)`, `(1,4)`. And `t_2` to intervals in the y-axis, i.e. `(-2,-1)`,`(-1,3)`.
Based on these intervals a grid of 6 squares is created and on each square a value of `W` corresponds. So the value `W[1]` corresponds to the square `(-1,0),(-2,-1)`, the value `W[2]` corresponds to the square `(-1,0),(-1,3)` etc.

So, how do I create that kind of heatmap??

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way that allows you to still use `geom_tile` by using your vectors to provide the `height` and `width` aesthetics:

```r
library(ggplot2)

d <- cbind(expand.grid(y = diff(t_2)/2 + head(t_2, -1), 
                       x = diff(t_1)/2 + head(t_1, -1)), W)

ggplot(d, aes(x, y, fill = W)) + 
  geom_tile(height = rep(diff(t_2), 3), width = rep(diff(t_1), each = 2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You first have to create a data.frame containing the coordinates of your six squares. Afterwards you could plot your heat map using `geom_rect`:

```r
t_1 = c(-1,0,1,4)
t_2 = c(-2,-1,3)
W = c(1,10,3,4,17,9)

# Create a df containig coordinates of the squares
grid <- data.frame(
  xmin = rep(rev(rev(t_1)[-1]), 2),
  xmax = rep(t_1[-1], 2),
  ymin = rep(rev(rev(t_2)[-1]), each = 3),
  ymax = rep(t_2[-1], each = 3),
  fill = W
)
grid
#>   xmin xmax ymin ymax fill
#> 1   -1    0   -2   -1    1
#> 2    0    1   -2   -1   10
#> 3    1    4   -2   -1    3
#> 4   -1    0   -1    3    4
#> 5    0    1   -1    3   17
#> 6    1    4   -1    3    9

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(grid) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = fill))
```

[image]